# Style Div based on inner class

Tags: css

I have a div button which has the inner class with `class="disabled"`. May I know how to detect based on the inner class?

```
<div class="nextBtn btnCls">
   <a id="content_0_nextLinkID" class="disabled" style="height: 202px;">
       Next Floor &gt;
   </a>
</div>
```

And I need to put styling when detect the a class is attached with disabled.

Comment: You can do this with Javascript, it is not possible via CSS.

Comment: .nxtBtn .disabled why you are not using this ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: You'll need Javascript/ jQuery for that. Is that a problem?

Comment: The difficulty that I faced is that when the code detects <a class="disabled">, how would I style my <div class="nextBtn btnCls"> div with some properties and disabled the button action.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your a is directly inside the div, I believe you can achieve what you want by simply styling the a element properly.

The below block stretches out the a to fill the parent div.

```
.btnCls > a {
    display: block;
}
```

Note that it also has the side effect of stretching out the parent div to accommodate the height of the a element, so you might want to adjust that (202px seems a bit too tall :-))

Then directly apply the style you want on the a element

```
.btnCls > a.disabled {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Note that if you are going to style anything on the border or outside of the bounds of the parent div (say the border or shadow), you are out of luck (as far as I know for now), but I'm guessing most button disables just change the background color or font.

Answer (score 0):

CSS works only the other way round: you can select child nodes based on parent nodes but you can not select parent nodes based on child nodes.

```
div[disabled] > a
```

This selects `a` which is a child of a `div` having the attribute `disabled`. See the specs for CSS 2:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching

and CSS 3:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: So are you saying that it is not possible for me to style the parent div based on its child's properties?

Comment: That is what I say. It is possible with XPath but not with CSS selectors.